# Best way to implement proximity alerts android

Tags: android, geolocation, batterylevel, proximitysensor

Hi I am developing android application and in my application i wanted to proximity alert for few location and those location are dynamic points mean location list can be change dynamically according users current location.

so I implemented proximity alerts in my application its working fine with entering and exiting events. But problem is that if I set expiration time as -1 it continuously uses GPS which drains device battery.

If I set expiration time then it stop searching for that location after expiration time exceeds.

And another question setting multiple proximity alerts causes battery consumption heavily?

How to use proximity alerts efficiently. Is there any better way to handle this scenario.

Need help.. Thank you...

Comment: Hi,did you find a way for doing this? I am trying to create a app which needs the proximity alerts. If you have any luck of how to save battery  please do update this question.